# How can I download Infrequently used dependencies in maven?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, maven-3, spark-cassandra-connector

Version: maven 3.6.3

I try to put this dependency into pom.xml,but it not auto download

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

so i use command line:

```
mvn dependency:get -DremoteRepositories=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 -DgroupId=com.datastax.spark -DartifactId=spark-cassandra-connector_2.11 -Dversion=2.4.3 -Dtransitive=false
```

but it give me couldn't download artifact error log :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Couldn't download artifact: Could not transfer artifact com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:jar:2.4.3

1. Do I need to upgrade remoteRepositories?
2. Why are some commonly used packages automatically downloaded quickly ? such as guava,commons-lang.
   Some new versions are always problematic to rely on for download,Is it no cache in
   repository?

How can I download the dependency? Thanks

Comment: This dependency resolves fine for me. It is located in the maven central repo. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11/2.4.3. So that you don't need to specify repositories. Have you tried re-importing maven dependencies? What is the IDE you are using?

Comment: Try `mvn clean install -U` and try fetching all the dependencies from maven central repo which are available there .

Comment: @Tanimak idea 2019.3

Comment: You can also try right click on pom.xml -> Maven -> Generate Sources and Update folders.

Comment: @Tanimak yes,i try it,but updating very slow.

Comment: @Pookly once downloaded to your local maven repo, you will be able to use it as other artifacts.

Comment: @Tanimak ok,thanks for your help

Comment: I would recommend to switch to SCC 2.5.0 - it's newer & has much more functionality & optimizations

Comment: @AlexOtt yes,I try to it,but it not Compatibili Cassandra Java Driver 3.x

Comment: that's true... but do you really need to use driver from Spark application?